# Python: Unit Tests/ Integration Tests: Workaround for file paths?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I have some unit tests and integration tests I need to run in a project. The problem I face is that sometimes files are read (as mock data) and dependent on where I start the test, the relative paths has to be changed.

Is there a solution to not changing the paths, even if tests are started from different directories? (like in pycharm sometimes from a directory called 'tests' or at other times from the directory 'unit')?

For example:

I run my tests within Pycharm from a "test" directory. In one of my unit tests I read a file with the path: "../data"
Sometimes I run my tests from a directory called "unit tests" which resides in the "test" directory. Now I would have to adapt my file path from above, otherwise my file would not be found.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph about not changing the paths.  Could you give an example how you would like your tests to behave?

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to solve the problem you describe:

- Write a wrapper script that first sets the working directory to a fixed path before running the tests.
- You could pass the absolute path in an environment variable to your test executable.
- Rather than reading test data from a file, incorporate the test data into your test code.